# How do I format chapter headers in a report without changing the chapter header of the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I created a report with a table of contents, and I formatted the chapter headers to look a certain way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{1ex}{ \LARGE \thechapter \ \  }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Data}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Data}

\end{document}
```

The table of contents looks like this:

[image: table of contents]

I want to format the chapter headers after the table of contents (1, 2, etc.) without changing the formatting of the "Contents" header of the table of contents. How do I do this? I want "0 Contents" to read "Contents" as is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the preamble

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}{}{0em}{}
```

and replace your line with the more correct

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE }{\thechapter}{1em}{}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Can you explain a little about why the first line fixes this? Also, the second line is a little different from mine because it places a line break between the chapter number and the chapter title, which I was trying to remove.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the final `\ \ `, which I interpreted as `\\ `. I'll fix that. The explanation for the first line is the `numberless` key: you can have a different formatting for numbered and unnumbered chapters.

Comment: @MichaelA: I just forgot one point: do you have any unnumbered chapters that you would  like to see in the table of contents (except the table of contents itself, of course)?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I don't foresee having any other unnumbered chapters that I want to see in the table of contents. When I add the appendix, I expect it will be numbered and included like the bibliography and the primary chapters.

Comment: The bibliography is an unnumbered chapter, usually…

Comment: What would I need to do to unnumber the bibliography, then?

Comment: This depends on how you produce your bibliography: via a `thebibliography` environment, or via a .bib file, and `bibtex` or`biblatex+biber`.

Comment: I use a .bib file and `\bibliography{nameofbibfile}`

Comment: Well, as far as I remember, in standard classes the bibliography is unnumbered.